# Designing an api fetching service, executorservice and mutable list of endpoints

Tags: java, api, executorservice

I have a few dozen API calls that my service has to make, but which calls, and how often I make them, depends on who is currently logged into the system.

So if I have 500 people currently logged into the system, their requests will have priority over someone who is currently not logged in.

How or what kind of collection should I use that is thread safe, and something that I can iterate over and mutate based on user priority, and other scores that I will determine based on which calls should be made first.

Would you suggest I use an executorservice for creating a set pool of threads?

Answer (score 1):

As for your first question regarding the collection, you could look at the [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) which is a thread-safe version of the PriorityQueue. You could implement the comparator to prioritize the items for users that are currently online.  I haven't used it, but I suspect it would not allow for dynamically changing the order based on the current state of the user, but would be ordered based on the state of the user when the item is added to the queue.

With that collection, you could use the executorservice or whatever other device to pull from the queue and execute the API call.